# Term for actively opting out of a requirement to see if it is truly required

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

There was a term or phrase I encountered years ago which encompassed the idea of not doing an action to see if there is any blowback.  If no blowback occurs then it is considered an efficiency improvement as that requirement can be skipped/omitted in the future.

Worker "I stopped filing my weekly TPS reports months ago and nobody has said anything so it seems clear they aren't looking at them."

Manager "Good catch, this is a XXXXX.  We will decommission this process and roll it out across the department."

I want to say this came either from accounting or corporate management domain.

EDIT:
As per clarification request, this would be the noun of what an improvement of this nature is.  Process improvement would be the general term, however a specific term for this type of process improvement exists.  Also it is specifically just not doing it rather than bringing attention to it as a problem.

Comment: Sounds like a vestige.

Comment: sounds like a "reverse acid test".

Comment: It’s unclear whether you’re asking about the action of resisting to test boundaries or a name for a requirement that has been determined to be unnecessary as a result of such a test or for the situation where such a superfluous requirement has been found.

Comment: I’m ***pushing back*** on this ***bureaucratic red-tape*** because eliminating it would be a good ***process improvement***